# html after {% block content %} and {% endblock content %} is showing before the content in Django?

Tags: html, django

I have base and child templates.

In my base HTML file I have this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

    </head>

        <body>
            <ul id="barra">
                <li>Inicio</li>       
                <li>Enlace1</li>
                <li>Enlace2</li>
                <li>Enlace3</li>
                <li>Enlace4</li>
                <li>Ayuda</li>
            </ul>

            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}

        </br>
            <a>asdasdasdasdasdasd</a>
        </body>
 </html>
```

But when I see the web in a browser, the "asdasdasdasdasdasd" is shown below URL and over {% block content}.
[image: See error image]

Does anyone knows the origin of this behavior, I think its a really simple structure and I cant get why it's failing? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: It has something to do with your CSS, could you post it? The behavior is as requested when just executing the above code.

Comment: Could you include the child template in the question? If after extending the base there is no {%block content%} and {% endblock %}, the child page code won’t be replaced where you expect it to

Comment: Thanks to both for quick reply. I just started from 0, with simple content, and then replacing it progressively until i had the final style working properly. I think it was about some missing  html tag. Thank you :)